# Vagrant box setup

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to setup `Hyperledger fabric` on my Windows 7 machine. I installed all the prerequisite for environment setup like: Go, Oracle VM, Vagrant.

I cloned the fabric folder from hyperledger site. While trying to run vagrant up, it throws me error like:

> connection aborted ,Retrying ....

It took SSH user name as: ubuntu and SSH password: password

I followed the steps from [link1](https://aether505.wordpress.com/2016/12/05/hyperledger-fabric-setup-step-by-step/) and [link2](https://bit-i-know.blogspot.com/2016/09/installation-of-hyperledger-fabric-on.html) for my setup.

Can any one suggest me how to solve this problem?

It would be great help for me if anyone share some solutions.

Please find the error screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: I am running in debug mode , I found the Error message as belowDEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
 INFO ssh: SSH not ready: #<Vagrant::Errors::SSHConnectionAborted: SSH connection was aborted! This usually happens when the machine is taking
too long to reboot or the SSH daemon is not properly configured on the VM.
First, try reloading your machine with `vagrant reload`, since a simple
restart sometimes fixes things. If that doesn't work, destroy your machine
and recreate it with a `vagrant destroy` followed by a `vagrant up`. If that
doesn't work, contact support.>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the docker setup? Seems to be the recommenced development environment.

To answer your question, Vagrant wants to use SSH keys for password-less access by default. Your `Vagrantfile` should point to SSH keys to use. Since you're on Windows you may need to generate these keys.

Comment: I have created SSH key using git in path C:\Users\<MY LOGIN>\.ssh\id_rsa file on windows. While running vagrant ssh-config I got the message that it point to virtualbox private key ($ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User ubuntu
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile D:/Projects/GoProjects/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/devenv/.
vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
)

Comment: I have created SSH key using git in path C:\Users\<MY LOGIN>\.ssh\id_rsa file on windows. While running vagrant ssh-config I got the message that it point to virtualbox private key ($ vagrant ssh-config Host default HostName 127.0.0.1 User ubuntu Port 2222 UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null StrictHostKeyChecking no PasswordAuthentication no IdentityFile D:/Projects/GoProjects/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/dev‌​env/. vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key IdentitiesOnly yes LogLevel FATAL )